# How long does your Japan visa need to be valid for the VFTF for Indians in Singapore?

Tags: indian-citizens, japan, transit-visas, singapore, visa-free-entry

So according to https://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=96 Indian citizens with a Japanese visa can enter into Singapore once during either the onward or return journey of their trip.

So my Japanese tourist visa shows the date of issue as 24th March and Date of expiry as 24th June. What this means according to the official who issued my visa is I can enter Japan at any time in this period and the I could stay for 90 days after that date. So hypothetically I could have entered Japan on 23rd June and stayed for 90 days after that. Anyways I entered Japan on 10th May and I could stay until 8th August. However I returned today and am currently at Singapore enroute back to India.  The immigration officer here says that I'm not eligible for the VFTF because my visa supposedly expired on 24th June.

Is she correct? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your visa allows you to enter a country during its validity and only during its validity.  Your visa expired on 24 June so is no longer valid to enter either Japan or Singapore.

Comment: Hmm is that so? I always presumed the Visa period was from the day you entered the country